# How to add CSS and HTML editor in my custom website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a website and already have the admin panel to post, add previlege, etc.
And my website is not using any CMS.

The problem is I want to edit my HTML and CSS (like wordpress do) directly from admin area.

Can Javascript / PHP do this?

Please don't suggest another 3rd party to do this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: _"Please don't suggest another 3rd party [library?] to do this"_ - what else do you expect? Code a complete fresh editor for you? But to answer your question: Yes, js & php can do this.

Comment: nope, i just need to know a little hint. like a reference code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how much customization you want.. If you want to just stylize your posts(typography)

Visit the link mentioned below.
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/

Or if you want to change the whole HTML design layouts, then you'll have to store designs in db, raw html and your css should have styles for them as well.

Comment: Well, I need the editor to directly edit the style.css and any html / php from my site.
I'll check this out